# which tag got priority between div and span tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question maybe an iteration! But, still I'm not satisfied with the explanation I found.

My question is: what would be consequences if I use span tag rather div tag? Both are non-semantic tag, I know that. Normally, we use div as a container and span for in-line markup. what if I only use span tag as a container?

Is there any priority at CSS for both the tags? I just want to be more clear about it.

Comment: There is no difference in CSS priority.

Comment: Who told you they're non-semantic? They both have their own part and different types of elements they're supposed to contain (block vs inline differences).

Comment: @Itay — The whole point of them is that they don't come with any semantics (and the minimum of default presentation). They are for use when HTML doesn't have anything that has the correct semantics for what you want to describe.

Comment: @Quentin there's still a big distance between what you're saying and calling them *non-semantic*

Answer (score 2):

> what would be consequences if I use span tag rather div tag?

- Different CSS is applied by default (`display: inline` instead of `display: block` being the main (and possibly only) difference).
- Your HTML might become invalid (depending on where you put the element and what you put inside it).

> Normally, we use div as a container and span for in-line markup. what if I only use span tag as a container?

It depends what you try to have it contain. Text? Links? Cites? A pile of other things? That's all fine. Divs? Paragraphs? Tables? A different pile of other things? Invalid HTML and you might get unexpected behaviour when the browser tries to generate a DOM from it.

> Is there any priority at CSS for both the tags?

No. Selector specificity only cares that you use a type selector (or some other kind of selector), not what particular type the element is.

See [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) for more details of how CSS determines which rules apply to an element.

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between `<div>` and `<span>` is how they are rendered by the browser **by default** (this can be changed with CSS). The former takes up 100% of the available width and causes a line break, while the latter tries to squeeze the content into the smallest area allowed.

Here's an image for reference: [image]
Like @amadan said, there are no differences in CSS priority.

Comment: That isn't true. That's just the default presentation (which can be changed with CSS). The real difference is what elements they can be children of and what elements they can contain.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I was referring to the default behavior. I'll edit my answer to include that.